# Use docker image in jenkins build and start background service

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am setting up a build in Jenkins and I'm using a docker image for the job.

When the container is running for the job I need to start a service (postgresql) in the container in the background and then continue with the work of the job.

I can't figure out how to start the service and leave the container running, ready for the following commands.

In my dockerfile I currently have

```
FROM php:5.6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      unzip \
      git \
      libpq-dev \
      libzip-dev \
      sudo \
      postgresql && \
  docker-php-ext-install \
      pdo_pgsql \
      zip

USER postgres
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
      psql -c "CREATE USER blah WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'blahblah';" && \
      createdb -O blah blahblahblah

USER root

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
service postgresql start
exec "$@"
```

And my Jenkinsfile is

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker { image 'myimage' }
  }
  stages {
    stage('run unit tests') {
      steps {
        dir('tests') {
          sh 'php composer.phar install --prefer-dist --no-progress'
          sh 'php codecept run unit'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I start the docker from the command line in interactive mode it works fine.
`sudo docker run -it myimage bash` results in an the container running, postgresql started, and awaiting input at bash.

But when Jenkins starts the docker I get the following error

```
docker run -t -d -u 997:995 -w /path/to/workspace -v /path/to/workspace:rw,z -v /path/to/workspace@tmp:/path/to/workspace@tmp:rw,z myimage cat
docker top containerid -eo pid,comm


Failed to run top 'containerid '. Error: Error response from daemon: Container containerid is not running
```

I've tried removing the entrypoint from the dockerfile, and putting the service start call in the jenkinsfile, but as Jenkins runs the docker with the jenkins user, which doesn't exist in the docker container, it can't start the service (permission denied). Even with sudo it returns an error `sudo: unknown uid 997: who are you?`

How can I have jenkins run a docker container when a job is triggered, somehow start postgresql, and proceed with the rest of the tasks.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Rob

Comment: can you try one thing in your `docker-entrypoint.sh` file like instead of `exec "$@"` write `tail -f /dev/null` or `tail -f /var/log/postgres.log` it will keep your container in running background and allow you to run your job. after completion of job you can stop/remove it with container name.I recommend to use `--name`  with your run command instead of `container-id` because you can fix it.

Comment: @chintanthakar I just tried that and it didn't make a difference to Jenkins, still get the same error about the container not running when trying to do the `docker top` command.  It is Jenkins that forms and calls the docker commands, so I don't know if I have control over using a container name rather than id, it's just what jenkins does.

Comment: can you just type same docker command in `Jenkinsfile` may be it is creating issue.

Comment: @chintanthakar not sure what you mean.

Comment: I've just tried using http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/ to start postgresql but I can't get that working either

Answer (score 1):

I've given up trying to get postgresql running in the same container, and have a separate container that is running postgresql by itself, and then linking it to the new container for the php stuff.  This approach is working fine.  It's a shame because I can't have multiple of the php containers running at the same time now as they will conflict on the database, rather than having their own dedicated database running internally, but at least it works.